# Microsoft Money 2005 - upgrade now or wait?

Tags: software-rec, finance, microsoft-money

I'm using Microsoft Money Small Business 2005 for very simple bookkeeping. It works well enough for what I need. Since MSFT discontinued Money, should I look to upgrade now while other apps are still able to import from Money 2005? Or do you think it's OK to wait. Will Quicken still be able to import from Money 2005 in 2-3 years?

[Please tag this question with microsoft-money, since I am not allowed to create new tags  yet.]

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/2769/now-that-ms-money-is-going-away-what-are-the-best-competitive-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you'll still be able to transfer your data a few years from now, you might want to go ahead and make the switch now while you *know* you can transfer it, and while Intuit support staff is [geared up](http://quicken.intuit.com/transfer-from-microsoft-money.jsp) to help MS Money refugees.

Comment: +1 Transfer now. The situation will not get better if you wait.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has now brought out, “[Money Plus Sunset](http://www.microsoft.com/money/sunset.mspx)”, this may buy some time but is not a long term solution as it is the end of the road.

> The Microsoft Money Plus Sunset
>   versions are replacements for expired
>   versions of Microsoft Money
>   Essentials, Deluxe, Premium, and Home
>   and Business. They allow existing
>   customers to use MoneyPlus to continue
>   accessing their data. Changes to the
>   new versions include file conversions
>   from older versions of Money, no
>   required activation, no online
>   services and no assisted support.
>   Microsoft Money Plus Sunset is
>   available now.
>
> We encourage consumers currently using
>   Money Plus with online services to
>   retain their current version to take
>   advantage of the online services until
>   they expire. The Sunset versions do
>   not support online services.